# RestKit Warning - WARNING: Failed mapping nested object: (null)

Tags: ios, ios5, warnings, restkit

I just started learning RestKit. I am trying to use it to get nearby venues using Foursquare apis. but every time I try " objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects " I get this warning "WARNING: Failed mapping nested object: (null)".

I am really confused. Following is my mapping code which is in init method:

```
 _objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"https://api.foursquare.com"];

    RKObjectMapping *locationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Location class]];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"address" toAttribute:@"address"];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"city" toAttribute:@"city"];
    [locationMapping mapKeyPath:@"state" toAttribute:@"state"];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:locationMapping forKeyPath:@"location"];

    RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Groups class]];
    [venueMapping mapRelationship:@"location" withMapping:locationMapping];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:venueMapping forKeyPath:@"groups"];

    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Response class]];
    [responseMapping mapRelationship:@"groups" withMapping:venueMapping];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:responseMapping forKeyPath:@"response"];

    return self;
```

Following is the code in "locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation "

```
    NSString *resourceURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v2/venues/search?ll=%f,%f&limit=10&client_id=LEA1MYN1Z1QWSBFIOA1T4FREVVNF0R1ADQKMA0AMGL3CN5N4&client_secret=M2W204MKEAO4KV5L4ZXUYWK2GC32PO0KT5PWYJQBP4FKBTMO",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourceURLString delegate:self];
[_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

and finally this code is in "objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects"

```
_objects = [objects retain];
NSLog(@"object that i receive is %@",objects);
```

Following is the response i get in console:

2012-02-26 13:15:39.872 restKitPractice[8609:690b] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:372 WARNING: Failed mapping nested object: (null)
2012-02-26 13:15:39.873 restKitPractice[8609:207] object that i receive is (
        "Response: 0x6b5cb20"
)

You can check the Venues json from Foursquare using this link:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.562362,-111.938689&limit=10&client_id=LEA1MYN1Z1QWSBFIOA1T4FREVVNF0R1ADQKMA0AMGL3CN5N4&client_secret=M2W204MKEAO4KV5L4ZXUYWK2GC32PO0KT5PWYJQBP4FKBTMO

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated as I am really struggling with this issue.

Thanks
Vik

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [object mapping docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).

Your mapping definitions do not match the json you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I've seen the same warning. The cause is that you have JSON like this `{"response":{}}` that you want to map to an object. Since there are no keys in the object, it essentially maps to `nil`. So, the warning is pretty harmless. You will not get a `Response` object back because the server essentially returned something that RestKit can't map because there are no keys in the JSON that match any of your attribute mappings. RestKit is letting you know that with the warning and falling back to not creating an object.